# C++ console input blocks so i can't kill thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows-8.1, user-input, blocking

My program has many different threads handling different things, and one of them deals with user input.

The other threads don't have much in the way of blocking calls, and those that do block are network based so will be interrupted or return gracefully when the socket is shut down.

However the user thread has calls to `std::cin` in order to grab the user input. The effect this has is while all the other threads are dead the user thread is still blocking on user input, and will only die the next time input is given.

Is there any way for me to check if there is any user input to grab before blocking?

I understand `cin.peek()` exists but from my experience, it blocks if there is nothing to read in. Assuming I'm using it correctly

My code is basically an infinite loop that stops when another thread switches the condition variable:

```
void doLoop()
{
    while (running) //running is shared between all threads and all others die quickly when it is false. It's set to true before the threads are started
    {
        string input = "";
        getline(cin, input);

        //Handle Input

    }
}
```

I'm on windows, using VS2013, and cannot use external libraries. I'm using windows.h and std throughout.

Comment: Depends on your actual OS, but you might be interested in check out for [`select()`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/select.2.html) or [`poll()`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/poll.2.html) to overcome these problems.

Comment: Should have mentioned that, I'm on windows

Comment: Can you just explicitly kill the user input thread when the program stops running?

Comment: Kill it how? I'm creating the thread as a std::thread, and didn't think there was a way to kill them remotely. I'd rather not pursue this, but will main thread termination kill remaining threads safely?

Comment: @ForceGaia That was clear to me, but since all that stuff actually is OS dependent, you should have tagged so maybe. The `std::thread` options might still give you some feasible solution.

Comment: altered the tags to include my OS

Comment: Search around Stack Overflow to see the discussions regarding thread termination. Boost has a mechanism for this, but std::thread does not.

Comment: Can't use boost for what I'm doing. This is for a university assignment, and I lose marks for using libraries other than std and  those included in windows.

I've been googling this for the best part of two hours (whihc is how i found `cin.peek()`) but nothing comes up that can help. Which brings me here

Comment: I am not certain, but pretty sure that `eof()` will do what you want: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/  (I'd have posted it as an answer if I were sure.)

Comment: @Zéychin - How would you use that exactly? it doesn't block, but I can't enter anything if I do the check before a `cin >> str` call. All i can see is that it returns true when an end of file is reached, how does that translate to user input?

Comment: "*The other threads don't have much in the way of blocking calls, and those that do block are network based so will be interrupted or return gracefully when the socket is shut down.*" Assuming by "shut down" you mean closed; no, they won't. (Are you literally calling `shutdown`?) This is a race condition and terrible things have happened in the real world due to coding like this. (Ask a separate question about why this is totally unsafe if you need more details.)

Comment: Hmmm, if you are using console input, then there are a bunch of low level functions to check the state of the input buffer, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684199(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Note that usually the thread handling user input is also the one managing so called worker threads, so in this usual setup the whole application would depend on user is to exit gracefully.

Comment: @didierc Generally you are right and the user thread is the one that initiates the stopping of threads, but in the case where the server has to close down first the loop dealing with receiving from the socket will be the one to initiate the stopping of threads.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I call `shutdown()`, wait, then close the socket. so if there are still any blocking `recv()` calls they then return with a  socket error. I check the error and handle it.

Comment: Not sure how a user would react to an application suddenly shutting down while she's inputting a command. Perhaps a better approach would be to split the service from UI (whether console based or graphical), and have the UI and service processes message each other.

Comment: @didierc Well the way this assignment is graded, I can pass with console only, but i can extend my mark by packaging it as a DLL behind a better interface. So once I've gotten a console version working, I can modify this so that the user input won't have this issue. But you raise a good point, it may be best it waits until the user enters their next command, that way they get something back saying "sorry the server is dead, prepare for the client to close" as an error message after their command rather than the program terminating mid-command

Comment: Why can't you compile with /MD in stead of /MT? Afaik this problem is only present in the static MSVC++ runtime library.

Comment: @user1320881 I don't really understand what you mean. I'm compiling in vs2013, I've not touched any project settings. what do those switches do? and how is it supposed to resolve the issue, what will happen differently?

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought you were having the main thread kill the thread that's stuck in the getline with terminatethread. The static runtime library can't kill a thread doing a getline for some reason, the dynamic one can.

Comment: @user1320881 at present I'm not doing anything, I'm trying to find a way to kill it. the killing would be done by another thread, not the main thread, which is why i was looking for a way to have a non-blocking console user input

Comment: If you used native functions, e.g., ReadFile, in the thread that is reading the console input, you could use CancelSynchronousIo in any other thread to cancel the ReadFile operation.  Alternatively, you could use ReadConsoleInput and WaitForMultipleObjects; note that the console handle is signaled when input is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is using futures to allow the user to input something with a time limit. You can then insert this code into your main loop

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <future>         // std::async, std::future
#include <chrono>         // std::chrono::milliseconds
#include <string>
using namespace std;


bool myAsyncGetline(string & result)
{
    std::cout<<"Enter something within the time limit"<<endl;
    getline(cin,result);
    return true;
}

int main()
{
  // call function asynchronously:
  string res;
  std::future<bool> fut = std::async (myAsyncGetline,res); 


  std::chrono::seconds span (20);
  if (fut.wait_for(span)==std::future_status::timeout)
    std::cout << "Too Late!";
  else
      cout<<"You entered "<<res<<" "<< endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This is available in VS2012 so you should be able to reproduce it.

The output is "Tool Late!" if getline is still working after the timeout (20s), otherwise it outputs the result.

I think that it is simpler than messing around with killing thread as the function stop by itself if the time limit is hit.
Tell me if you need help integrating it into your existing code I can assist.

Comment: Looks like a place to start, but I don't think it'll work. the way i see it every time myAsyncGetline is called the timer immediately starts. so if the user starts typing on the 19th second of that timer, a second later it times out and they lose their input. However it has given me an idea, as it means that i can keep checking if a string is empty (as it'll only have something in it when the user hits enter), restart teh async if the string isn't empty, and i can plonk the timeout after the loop so i can kill the async when the thread is supposed to die. I'll have a mess about with this.

Comment: ok keep me updated I am curious about that bcz I think future can simplify code.

Comment: yes, and that's what makes me question this method. will fut.wait_for(span) actually kill the thread?

Comment: It will kill it if the timeout is reached. here for more details. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/async/ and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/857201/Cplusplus-Concurrency-New

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the C++ Standard does not offer a way of checking the standard input without blocking. Since you are willing to use platform specific functions, 'kbhit()' might suit your needs but it has been deprecated in Windows. An alternative is offered, `_kbhit()`. Of course this is not portable to other platforms.

This is the link to MSDN: [_kbhit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx)

Comment: that link mentions "This API cannot be used in applications that execute in the Windows Runtime" what exactly does that mean? is that only if i were to pack it as a DLL?

Comment: @ForceGaia It means you cannot use it in Windows Store apps.

Comment: checking kbhit() before doing the getline would still result in the same problem if the user has begun typing but did not enter yet, or changed his mind and aborts entering text.

Comment: @ForceGaia you'll have to use `get()` instead of `getline()`